# Cannot post integer value from angular with httpclient to WebAPI

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

[image]

[image]

`totalPrice` is always 0, I can post any entity but I cannot post just int or string.
And I think that its about `JSON` but not sure how to post only an integer.
It works when I post an integer by using `swagger` or `postman`. 
Thank you.

Comment: does your network tab show you passing 8000 in your body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Angular sends the request content-type `application/json` so your dotnet webapi action is expecting some sort of model to bind with that JSON. Using `[FromBody]` attribute should fix your problem.

This is an example I just created to test.

API:

```
[HttpPost("add")]
public IActionResult Add([FromBody] int totalPrice)
{
    return Ok("RESULT: " + totalPrice);
}
```

POST Request:

```
POST https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast/add
Content-Type: application/json

8000
```

Response:

```
POST https://localhost:5001/weatherforecast/add

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 07 Apr 2021 19:39:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Server: Kestrel
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

RESULT: 8000

Response code: 200 (OK); Time: 52ms; Content length: 12 bytes
```